# How would you find the number of paths to this tree in Java?

Tags: java, search, tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am trying to find the number of paths to a tree represented this way:

```
1 4
2 4
3
4
-1
```

-1 represents the end and each number represents the next node. Each line is a node and their number starts with 0. So, in this particular instance, there are 3 paths: 0>1>2>3>4>-1, 0>4>-1, and 0>1>4>-1.

[image]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PathFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> wholeList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, " ");

            ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                temp.add(st.nextToken());
            }
            wholeList.add(temp);
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `0 1 4 -1` come from?

Comment: Well, I'm going from row 0 to 1 to 4 to end

Comment: You you draw your example tree more like a tree? It's pretty confusing to read

Comment: Row 0 connects to: 1 4, Row 1 connects to: 2 4, Row 2 connects to: 3, Row 3 connects to: 4, and Row 4 connects to: end (represented by -1)

Comment: a. The numeric representation of the graph is not clear. To me it looks like 0>1 , 0>4, 1>2, 1>4, 2>3, 3>4, 4>-1. b. Hard code the data instead of using scanner. c. I don't the dfs code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you change your arrays so that they contain integer numbers and not strings. Then you can use a recursive solution:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PathFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<List<Integer>> wholeList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, " ");

            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                temp.add(Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken()));
            }
            wholeList.add(temp);
        }
        countRoutes(wholeList, 0);
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    
    private static int count = 0;

    private static void countRoutes(List<List<Integer>> tree, int nodeFrom) {
        for (Integer target : tree.get(nodeFrom)) {
            if (-1 == target) {
                count++;
            } else {
                countRoutes(tree, target);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to see the routes you can modify the method a bit:

```java
private static void printRoutes(List<List<Integer>> tree, int nodeFrom, String route) {
    for (Integer target : tree.get(nodeFrom)) {
        if (-1 == target) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(route + "->-1");
        } else {
            printRoutes(tree, target, route + "->" + target);
        }
    }
}
```

and call it from the main program as

```java
printRoutes(wholeList, 0, "0");
```

**Update 03-Mar-2021**

A more efficient way is to cache the number of paths leading to the end from a given node:

```java
private static int countRoutes(List<List<Integer>> tree, 
                               int nodeFrom, 
                               int[] pathsNumber)
{
    if (nodeFrom == -1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (pathsNumber[nodeFrom] >= 0) {
        return pathsNumber[nodeFrom];
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer target : tree.get(nodeFrom)) {
        sum += countRoutes(tree, target, pathsNumber);
    }
    pathsNumber[nodeFrom] = sum;
    return sum;
}
```

Then in the main method you initialize the array pathsNumber and call this method as following (-1 means that we have not calculated number of paths leading to the exit from this node yet):

```java
int[] pathsNumber = new int[wholeList.size()];
Arrays.fill(pathsNumber, -1);
System.out.println(countRoutes(wholeList, 0, pathsNumber));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! That's very helpful

Comment: For some reason, this is REALLY slow. I'm trying to add memoization. But, it's still not good enough

Comment: There was no information about performance requirements in your original post. You can try the updated version, it should be faster because it does not construct paths from already visited nodes again.